# Creating a snap package for a programming language

Tags: snap

I have tried snapcrafters forum, but AU format can reach a wider audience. My question is regarding the creation of a snap for the Swift Programming Language. A questions that I cannot find answer is whether snap allows access for binaries that are in essence libraries, is it even possible to generate a usable snap of something like a programming language?

I managed to create and [released a snap](https://github.com/lf-araujo/swift-snap) that installs the binaries correctly, however these are not accessible to the system after installation, so I decided to change my approach and attempt the creation of a snap based on the source.

Installation using cmake usually works with:

```
## 1. Install prerequisites
sudo apt-get install git cmake ninja-build clang python uuid-dev libicu-dev icu-devtools libbsd-dev libedit-dev libxml2-dev libsqlite3-dev swig libpython-dev libncurses5-dev pkg-config libblocksruntime-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev autoconf libtool systemtap-sdt-dev tzdata

## 2. Download source
mkdir swift-source
cd swift-source
# if using ssh…
git clone git@github.com:apple/swift.git
./swift/utils/update-checkout --clone-with-ssh
# alternately, if using http…
git clone https://github.com/apple/swift.git
./swift/utils/update-checkout --clone

## 3. Build source
cd swift
utils/build-script --release-debuginfo
```

However, my attempt is not working:

```
name: swift
version: 'master'
summary: The Swift Programming Language
description: |
  Swift is a high-performance system programming language. It has a clean and
  modern syntax, offers seamless access to existing C and Objective-C code and
  frameworks, and is memory safe by default.

grade: stable
confinement: classic

parts:
  swift:
    plugin: cmake
    source: https://github.com/apple/swift.git
#    source-tag: 'swift-3.0.2-RELEASE'
    build-packages:
      - git
      - cmake
      - ninja-build
      - clang
      - python
      - uuid-dev
      - libicu-dev
      - icu-devtools
      - libbsd-dev
      - libedit-dev
      - libxml2-dev
      - libsqlite3-dev
      - swig
      - libpython-dev
      - libncurses5-dev
      - pkg-config
      - libblocksruntime-dev
      - libcurl4-openssl-dev
      - autoconf
      - automake
      - libtool
      - systemtap-sdt-dev
      - python-sphinx
    build: |
      ./utils/update-checkout --clone
      ./utils/build-script -Rt -j 1
    install: |
      cp -a build/Ninja-ReleaseAssert/* $SNAPCRAFT_PART_INSTALL/
```

Installation using ubuntu-make is even easier, but there is no snap plugin for umake:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-make
umake swift
```

- How can I make a library be accessed by the system in a snap?

Comment: Keep in mind that most snaps are self-contained and isolated from the system to some extent, if this is a system library that should be accessed by the system at a whole snapping it might not be the best solution...